# Cancel Password Manager Auto Type

Tags: passwords, automation, keepass

How would I cancel a password auto type (initiated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) after Keepass begins typing?

I've tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly, but to no avail

Comment: Wait till it finishes?

Comment: That is not an option in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try Win+L

I don't know a good way to cancel auto-type. I don't think there is one. At least I didn't find anything in the options.

Even with the options below, there is no elegant way to break out of a currently running auto-type.

Assuming you are on windows: The only thing that worked for my was to immediately lock the workstation with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

#### General Auto-type safety

Auto-type is a bit a of a foot gun for me.
You can set these options to make it a bit safer:

[image: KeePass Options: Auto-Type]

#### Another idea: remove ENTER from auto-tye entry

If you want avoid typing and sending your passwords into the wrong window you could also try to remove the final ENTER key from the auto-type sequence.

That will make it less comfortable. You will have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> manually before you can actually log in. But it may also give you another chance to not post the password somewhere it doesn't belong.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the original question, your "another idea" is a suitable compromise.

Comment: With the target window option set, you effectively *do* have a way to cancel it: just Alt+Tab. So this was a very welcome find. :)